# PowerMock + Robolectric + Dagger2. Part I

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, dagger-2, powermockito

This question was created from first part of [PowerMock + Robolectric + Dagger2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689722/powermock-robolectric-dagger2) 
So i'm a little bit again. Sorry. 
 
I test custom view class which contain:

1. android ui elements
2. some logic
3. static methods callings
4. dagger2 dependencies

So i use next tools for testing

1. Robolectric for UI elements mocking
2. unit tests for logic testing
3. PowerMock for static methods mocking

Robolectric + PowerMock integration problem is known and solution is known - https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/Using-PowerMock 
But with this solution dagger2 dependencies fail.


**Attention to code**
My custom view - *ProgressTextView*:

```
public class ProgressTextView extends TextView {

    private String defaultText;
    private int fileSize;
    private String fileSizeString;
    private FileDownloaderI fileDownloader;

    @Inject
    FileDownloaderManager fileDownloaderManager;

    Subscription downloadProgressChannelSubscription;
    Subscription downloadCancelChannelSubscription;

    public ProgressTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        provideDependency();
    }

    public ProgressTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        provideDependency();
    }

    public ProgressTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        provideDependency();
    }

    private void provideDependency() {
        ApplicationSIP.get().applicationComponent().inject(this);
    }

}
```

*ApplicationSIP*:

```
public class ApplicationSIP extends Application {

    public static volatile Context applicationContext;

    @NonNull
    private AppComponent appComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        applicationContext = getApplicationContext();
        Logger.registerLogger(this);

        appComponent = prepareApplicationComponent().build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
    }

    @NonNull
    protected DaggerAppComponent.Builder prepareApplicationComponent() {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(getApplicationContext()))
                .tGModule(new TGModule());
    }

    @NonNull
    public AppComponent applicationComponent() {
        return appComponent;
    }

    @NonNull
    public static ApplicationSIP get() {
        return (ApplicationSIP) applicationContext.getApplicationContext();
    }

}
```

*AppComponent*:

```
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, TGModule.class, MediaModule.class, StaticModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {   
    void inject(ApplicationSIP applicationSIP);
    void inject(ProgressDownloadView progressDownloadView);
    void inject(ProgressTextView progressTextView);
}
```

And *ProgressTextViewTest*:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricUnitTestRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*" })
@PrepareForTest(Formatter.class)
public class ProgressTextViewTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
    Activity activity;

    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {
        // PowerMockito
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Formatter.class);
        Mockito.when(Formatter.formatFileSize(anyObject(), anyInt())).thenReturn("");
        // Robolectic
        activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(Activity.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void init_FileDownloaded() {
        ProgressTextView progressTextView = new ProgressTextView(activity);
        ...
    }
}
```

So when i start this test i get next exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tg.osip.ApplicationSIP.get(ApplicationSIP.java:64)
at com.tg.osip.ui.general.views.ProgressTextView.provideDependency(ProgressTextView.java:60)
at com.tg.osip.ui.general.views.ProgressTextView.<init>(ProgressTextView.java:46)
at com.tg.osip.ui.general.views.ProgressTextViewTest.init_FileDownloaded(ProgressTextViewTest.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement$1.run(PowerMockRule.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(WhiteboxImpl.java:1873)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.doInvokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:773)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeMethod(WhiteboxImpl.java:638)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeMethod(Whitebox.java:401)
at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:98)
at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:78)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:49)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

If you change robolectric activity init placing:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricUnitTestRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "org.mockito.*", "org.robolectric.*", "android.*" })
@PrepareForTest(Formatter.class)
public class ProgressTextViewTest {

    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
    Activity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(Activity.class);

    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {
        // PowerMockito
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Formatter.class);
        Mockito.when(Formatter.formatFileSize(anyObject(), anyInt())).thenReturn("");
    }

    @Test
    public void init_FileDownloaded() {
        ProgressTextView progressTextView = new ProgressTextView(activity);
        ...
    }
}
```

I get other exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:569)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:369)
at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:94)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.QuickWriter.flush(QuickWriter.java:73)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.PrettyPrintWriter.flush(PrettyPrintWriter.java:342)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:858)
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:843)
at org.powermock.classloading.DeepCloner.clone(DeepCloner.java:53)
at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:89)
at org.powermock.classloading.ClassloaderExecutor.execute(ClassloaderExecutor.java:78)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockStatement.evaluate(PowerMockRule.java:49)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Answer (score 2):

Before answering your question. I would say:

1. Your view is doing/knowing too much. I'm talking about knowledge of `FileDownloaderManager` and knowledge about how to get dependencies
2. Since you're using injection I would wrap static functions into a class and inject it. It will be much easier to write/maintain tests
3. Even name of class `AppComponent` says that it should not know about how to inject a view. Think about scoped injections
4. Some minors with `applicationContext`. Why it is `volatile`, do you expect it to be accessed from non-main thread? It is already `ApplicationSIP` why do you need play with application context and casting?

Finally to the answer. The first stack trace says that the `appContext` is null. So `onCreate` of your app was not called. I don't see the code of `RobolectricUnitTestRunner` but I assume the problem is in the usage of the **PowerMock**. The second stack trace kind of proof for that. So I would say the answer is to stop usage of the **PowerMock**.

Comment: Thanks, Eugen, for answer!) Yes, maybe my view doing too much. But this views are in one of ViewHolders in RecyclerAdapter of RecyclerView. If i click to this view, i want to download file. So view have to show progress and result of downloading. I don't know how to get view from recyclerView or recyclerAdapter and correct update him without updating of full ViewHolder. So for Presenters and Interacts in Fragment i use Subcomponent. Yes, it's comfortable

Comment: Now i use wrap class for static methods and inject it)

Comment: In RobolectricUnitTestRunner i set ApplicationSIPTest. So in ApplicationSIPTest i provide test modules

Comment: And about PowerMock. With wrap classes we can live without it)

Comment: The direction of control should be opposite. You can use something like EvenBus for progress notification or keep a weak reference to progress listener (which view will implement). But the main idea - view is plain and orphan as possible and adapter/presenter are updating view outside

Comment: But FileDownloaderManager gives event channels for View like EventBus. And View does updates from events from this channels and nothing more or other business logic. So i am very grateful to you for this good comments)

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**
Don't use PowerMock with Robolectric and Dagger2. It's not safe.
Now i use wrap classes for static methods and inject this classes with Dagger2 helping. So there are not static methods in my testing class and PowerMock does not need. 
I think that it is quite normal variant.
And thanks Eugen Martynov for helping.